# Angular 7 service not acting as a singleton

Tags: angular, typescript, service, singleton

I used `ng generate` to create a service. I initialize an array and change a flag, but when I route to a different page the array is empty and the flag is false.

My service starts with

`@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`

I understood that would create a application-wide singleton service, but I've only used services on single page applications before now. Is it different with multi-page applications/routing?

edit: I've tried the field's as static which did not work either.

edit 2: This is more or less my problem: [angular-7bp9kn.stackblitz.io](http://angular-7bp9kn.stackblitz.io) Initialize on the home page, and display (true). Navigate to admin (after it's been initialized on home) and display (false).

Comment: If it's a completely different page (not a different route of a SPA) your value won't be saved since the application is destroyed.

Comment: Ah, yes it seems to be a different page. Do I use pound signs to do routing for an SPA?

Comment: You should use @angular/router module to achieve routing in Angular.

Comment: I was, this is what I have in my app routing module:

`const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'submit', component: SubmitComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
  { path: 'calendar', component: CalendarComponent },
  { path: 'edit', component: EditComponent }
];`

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, in a stackblitz.

Comment: Good idea, this is more or less my problem: https://angular-7bp9kn.stackblitz.io/home

Initialize on the home page, and display (true). Navigate to admin (after it's been initialized on home) and display (false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe ( from your stackblitz example above) your problem is the fact that you're using `href` instead of `routerLink="/home"` directive. And since `href` will do a complete reload of your page with a new uri, seems legit that the service will be reinitialized since the whole app is being bootstraped from scratch.

So bottom line, if you just replace `href` to `routerLink` there will be only one instance of your service through the app.

You can read more about it here [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: That solves it friend, at least in stackblitz. I'll go try it out in the office tomorrow. Bless.